resilience4J and springcloud-openfeign readTimeOut
I want to know whether
resilience4j.timelimiter.instances.feignClienA.timeoutDuration
in resilience4j configuration works for readTimeOut of spring-cloud openfeign feignClienA.
My project is configured like this but it doesn't work. When I debugged, I found that feign actually gets the options parameter through feign.SynchronousMethodHandler#findOptions to set readTimeout, but I don't see where to inject this parameter.
The decorator in resilience4j-feign only provides CircuitBreaker Bulkhead and no timelimiter.
So how can I make my configuration take effect?
my yaml configs
## timeout
resilience4j:
  timelimiter:
    instances:
      DataProcessFeignServiceprocessInitializeProcessTaskInitRequest:
        timeoutDuration: 240s
        cancel-running-future: true


my feign client

@FeignClient(value = "clearance-data-process-ib", fallbackFactory = DataProcessFeignServiceFallBack.class)
public interface DataProcessFeignService {

    @PostMapping("/service/process-task/process-initialize")
    @Operation(method = "POST", summary = "initialize")
    ServerResponse<Boolean> processInitialize(@Valid @RequestBody ProcessTaskInitRequest request);
}

http test
    @GetMapping("/feignTest")
    public ApiResponse<String> feignTest() {

        // extracted();
        ProcessTaskInitRequest request = new ProcessTaskInitRequest();
request.setDeclarationWaybillIdList(Lists.newArrayList("hello"));
        request.setTaskType("DATA_PRESS");
        log.info("feignTest request:{}", JsonUtil.toJsonString(request));
         dataProcessFeignService.processInitialize(request);
        return ApiResponse.success();
    }

server side  sleep 300s
    /**
     * Initialize
     *
     * @param request 
     * @return Response
     */
    @PostMapping("/process-initialize")
    @Operation(method = "POST", summary = "Initialize")
    public ServerResponse<Boolean> processInitialize(@Valid @RequestBody ProcessTaskInitRequest request) {
        try {
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ServerResponse.success(Boolean.TRUE);
    }

The request should time out in 240 seconds, but now it falls back in about 60 seconds because the feign option defaults to 60 seconds.

You can add config to application.properties like so :
spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.default.read-timeout=300000


Thanks , you are right  I can set the feign timeout long enough for the timelimiter to take effect. But this is not what I expected. I thought he should dynamically set the timeout in feign options according to the timelimiter when creating the request.
